# Get content from url after redirected

Tags: php, regex, twitter

I am trying to set up a tool to get someone's Twitter ID without using twitter's API.

In my example, my username is quixthe2nd.

So if you enter someone's twitter username in this link:

```
https://twitter.com/quixthe2nd/profile_image?size=original
```

It would redirect to:

```
https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1116692743361687553/0P-dk3sF.jpg
```

The ID is `1116692743361687553`. It is listed after `https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/`.

My code is:

```
$url = "https://twitter.com/quixthe2nd/profile_image?size=original";
function get_redirect_target($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $headers = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    // Check if there's a Location: header (redirect)
    if (preg_match('/^Location: (.+)$/im', $headers, $matches))
        return trim($matches[1]);
    // If not, there was no redirect so return the original URL
    // (Alternatively change this to return false)
    return $url;
}
function get_redirect_final_target($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // follow redirects
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1); // set referer on redirect
    curl_exec($ch);
    $target = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($target)
        return $target;
    return false;
}


    $s = $target;
    if(preg_match('/profile_images\/\K[^\/]+/',$s,$matches)) {
        print($matches[0]);
    }
```

My code doesn't output anything. How would I be able grab that via PHP?

Comment: _“My code doesn't output anything”_ - and why should it, neither of those two functions get _called_ anywhere. And $target does not get a value assigned anywhere. So if this code does not even show an error message - then please go enable proper PHP error reporting first of all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex and grab your value from group1,

```
profile_images\/([^\/]+)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LVVC4W/1)**

Alternatively, you can use `\K` so your full match is your intended text.

```
profile_images\/\K[^\/]+
```

**[Regex Demo using `\K`](https://regex101.com/r/LVVC4W/2)**

**[PHP Code Demo](https://rextester.com/VRESA40203)**

```
$s = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1116692743361687553/0P-dk3sF.jpg";
if(preg_match('/profile_images\/\K[^\/]+/',$s,$matches)) {
    print($matches[0]);
} else {
    echo "Didn\'t match";
}
```

Prints,

```
1116692743361687553
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried implementing what you said and the output is blank. I updated my post, please look over my post again

Comment: @ParsaYazdani: Your code regex wise looks fine but there seems some problem with your `$target` as it is not defined properly due to which it gives this error `Notice: Undefined variable: target in /in/EGu2F on line 34` You need to correct your PHP code so your `$target` variable gets populated with the value of that URL

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Ah you are  right, that not clear when the question says `My code is:`.

Comment: @ Thefourthbird: Sorry for the confusion